# STM32 and uCOS+uGUI

Tags: microcontroller, arm

1. Can I use STM32F103VCT6 with uCOSII2.91 and uCGUI3.90A ?
   Because from datasheet I saw the flash memory of STM32F103VCT6 is 256Kb
   and the result of compiling uCOSII2.91 and uCGUI3.90A is 689K
   I'm using Keil4 for compiling uCOSII and uCGUI.
2. If I want to update or customize the display on LCD, 
   The step that I must take :

   1. Modify uCOSII and uCGUI
   2. Compile them
   3. Upload to hardware using JLink,

Am I doing the right step ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are showing us the size of the hex file on your development machine's disk, rather than the size of the binary image it represents.  It is the latter which must fit in flash memory.

As a hex file is a printable ASCII representation, and has addresses, byte counts, and checksums per line, it is going to be on the order of 2.5-3x the size of the image it represents.

Also, you may not have set your toolchain to strip unused code.  For example, in a gcc-based toolchain you would specify `--gc-sections` to the linker.

Answer (score 0):

Memory footprint should not be a problem, you are not using the whole library at once, your tools set should link only the functions actually used. I find it hard to believe that the uCOS excellent product would be so memory hungry (at least not for basic functionality).

You also need to select /or write/ the LCD driver for your display and controller, but yes, you are doing fine.